# Provide some value to @Valid annotation and using that value change validation in isValid() method

Tags: spring, spring-boot, validation, annotations, spring-annotations

I am using two databases in my project and while validating filters provided in the request body, For some request I need validation from db1 and for some I need validation from db2.
I have mapped values and its corresponding types in one enum. But how do I determine which mapping I have to use for that particular filter provided in the request body.

Below is my controller demo:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/v1/abc")
public PageableDto getAll{Something}(
            @RequestAttribute UserClaim userClaim,
            @Valid SearchParametersDto searchParametersDto,
            @RequestBody @Valid List<FilterDto> filters)
```

This needs to be validated using DB1.

```
@PostMapping(path = "/v1/xyz")
    public PageableDto getAll{Something}(
            @RequestAttribute UserClaim userClaim,
            @Valid SearchParametersDto searchParametersDto,
            @RequestBody @Valid List<FilterDto> filters)
```

This needs to be validated using DB2.

In the FilterDto class, I have created annotation.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@FilterValidatorBehaviour
public class FilterDto {
    String name;
    String operation;
    String value;

    @JsonIgnore
    public DataBaseTypeObject getObjectWithFieldName(MappingEnum mapping) {
        //return get map with enum name map
        return mapping.getMappingMap().get(name);
    }
}
```

In the annotation implementation class. I have overridden isValid method as below.

```
@Override
    public boolean isValid(FilterDto filterDto, ConstraintValidatorContext ctx) {
       return filterDto.getValue().getClass().equals(
filterDto.getObjectWithFieldName(MappingEnum.DB1_MAPPING).getType()); 
   
 }
```

Below is MappingEnum class:

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Getter
public enum MappingEnum {

        DB1_MAPPING(Map.ofEntries(
                Map.entry("field1",new DB1Object("field1", String.class)),
                Map.entry("field2",new DB1Object("field2", String.class)),
                Map.entry("field3",new DB1Object("field3", String.class)),
                )),

        DB2_MAPPING(Map.ofEntries(
                Map.entry("field1",new DB2Object("field1", String.class)),
                Map.entry("field2",new DB2Object("field2", String.class)),
                Map.entry("field3",new DB2Object("field3", String.class)),
                )),


        private final Map<String, ? extends DataBaseTypeObject> mappingMap;
```

Here DB1Object and DB2Object are subclasses of DataBaseTypeObject.

Any help in the direction of a solution would be great help??

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to move the `@FilterValidatorBehaviour` annotation from `FilterDto` to the controller itself. The downside is that because you pass a list, you'll have to refactor the validator to accept a `List<FilterDto>` in stead of just a `FilterDto`.

The benefit is that you can add custom properties to your `@FilterValidatorBehaviour` annotation. For example, you could create a property that contains a `MappingEnum`:

```java
@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({PARAMETER}) // Make sure to set PARAMETER
@Constraint(validatedBy = FilterValidatorBehaviourValidator.class)
public @interface FilterValidatorBehaviour {
    MappingEnum value(); // Add this
    String message() default "{filterValidatorBehaviour}";
    Class<?>[] groups() default { };
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };
}
```

To read this `value` property, you can implement the `initialize()` method in your `ConstraintValidator` and set it as a field:

```java
@Override
public void initialize(FilterValidatorBehaviour constraintAnnotation) {
    this.mappingEnum = constraintAnnotation.value(); // Read mappingEnum from annotation
}
```

Now you can use `this.mappingEnum` in your `isValid()` method. Make sure not to forget that you have to refactor your validator froù `ConstraintValidator<FilterValidatorBehaviour, FilterDto>` to `ConstraintValidator<FilterValidatorBehaviour, List<FilterDto>>`.

After that, you can use `@FilterValidatorBehaviour(MappingEnum.DB1_MAPPING)` or `@FilterValidatorBehaviour(MappingEnum.DB2_MAPPING)` in your controller. For example:

```java
@PostMapping(path = "/v1/abc")
public PageableDto getAll{Something}(
            @RequestAttribute UserClaim userClaim,
            @Valid SearchParametersDto searchParametersDto,
            // Add the @FilterValidatorBehaviour annotation
            @RequestBody @Valid @FilterValidatorBehaviour(MappingEnum.DB1_MAPPING) List<FilterDto> filters) {
    // TODO: implement
    return null;
}
```